# How to get string using xpath in python bs4?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, lxml, xml.etree

I need to get a string into a li tag using python and bs4. I'm trying with the code below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree

html_doc = """
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <section id="page">
         <div class="content">   
            <div class="box">  
               <ul>
                  <li>Name: Peter</li>
                  <li>Age: 21</li>
                  <li>Status: Active</li>
               </ul> 
            </div>
         </div>
      </section>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')
dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))
print (dom.xpath('/html/body/div/section/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[3]'))
```

That one returns:
*[<Element li at 0x7fc640e896c0>]*

but the desired result is the li tag text like below:
*Status: Active*

How to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xpath just you have to use `text()` method

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree

html_doc = """
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <section id="page">
         <div class="content">   
            <div class="box">  
               <ul>
                  <li>Name: Peter</li>
                  <li>Age: 21</li>
                  <li>Status: Active</li>
               </ul> 
            </div>
         </div>
      </section>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')
dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))
print(dom.xpath('/html/body/div/section/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[3]/text())
```

Output:

```
 ['Status: Active']
```

#OR

```
for li in dom.xpath('/html/body/div/section/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[3]/text()'):
    txt=li.split()[1]
    print(txt)
```

Output:

```
Active
```

#OR

```
print(' '.join(dom.xpath('/html/body/div/section/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[3]/text()')))
```

Output:

```
Status: Active
```

#OR

```
print(''.join(dom.xpath('//*[@class="box"]/ul/li[3]/text()')))
```

Output:

```
Status: Active
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below (**no external lib required**)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = """
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <section id="page">
         <div class="content">   
            <div class="box">  
               <ul>
                  <li>Name: Peter</li>
                  <li>Age: 21</li>
                  <li>Status: Active</li>
               </ul> 
            </div>
         </div>
      </section>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
"""
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
print(root.find('.//ul')[-1].text)
```

output

```
Status: Active
```